# Using Socket.io across all Node.js project files

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I've been trying to set up Socket.io to work on all files, but all I have been able to do was to export the `io` function outside:

```
require("./socket")(io);
```

And in the file:

```
module.exports = io => {
  io.on("connection", socket => {
  });
};
```

How do I acess this `io` variable on any other file?

If I export the `io` variable, it is `undefined` because the socket.io isn't loaded yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I decided to do is export the io and instead of requiring it right away, I made a getter function which I use whenever I need it. Ugly but works.

```
function getIo() {
  return require("../app").io;
}
```